# Fastest way to write BIG pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, file

I ran a test which tested 10 ways to write and 10 ways to read a DataFrame. I found the test [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/io.html#io-perf) (I made some ajustements and added Parquet to the list) The best ways were :

```
df.to_feather('test.feather') :
39.34544535900204s

table=pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, "test_parquet_write_snappy_dict.parquet",
               use_dictionary=True, version='2.0', compression='snappy') :
40.6873751259991s

table=pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df, nthreads=4)
pq.write_table(table, "test_parquet_write_snappy_dict.parquet",
               use_dictionary=True, version='2.0', compression='snappy') :
41.051620177000586s
```

for the writing

and

```
pd.read_hdf('test_fixed.hdf', 'test') :
1.5275615360005759

pd.read_feather('test.feather') :
20.635139821002667

pd.read_pickle('test.pkl') :
37.21131302599679
```

for the reading.

Here's the DataFrame :

```
sz = 50000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': randn(sz), 'B': randn(sz), 'C': randn(sz), 'D': randn(sz)})
```

I have two questions. How `read_hdf` is 20 times fastest than read_feather while `to_hdf` isn't even in the first three of the write tests ?

And second one, 40 seconds is still too slow for my needs. Would there be a way to improve that speed ? Either by using different parameters with `to_feather` or `write_table` or using a function/module I doesn't know about ?

I'm not asking for someone to look up for me, I can do this myself and I don't want to waste anybody's time. I'm looking for someone who already know this problem and could lead me to the fastest way he knows.

Comment: I'd take the HDF read test, with such a difference in speed, with a grain of salt. Maybe also calculate a "checksum" (say, the sum of one column?) for the read data and compare it to a known value. This would make sure your IO is trustworthy, and also makes sure things aren't being loaded lazily.

Comment: Alright. HDF read test was my bad. It's not fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not exactly an answer per se, but here's a more thorough benchmark of various methods for data like yours...

```
import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn, randint


def generate_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "dt": randint(1_600_000_000, 1_700_000_000, size=n) * 1000,
            "a": randn(n),
            "b": randn(n),
            "c": randn(n),
        }
    )
    df.dt = pd.to_datetime(df.dt, unit="s")
    df.set_index("dt", inplace=True)
    return df


def benchmark(df, name, saver, loader):
    verify(df, loader, saver)
    save_timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: saver(df))
    load_timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: loader().a.sum())
    save_n, save_time = save_timer.autorange()
    load_n, load_time = load_timer.autorange()
    total_time = (load_time / load_n) + (save_time / save_n)
    print(
        f"{name:<15s} : "
        f"{save_n / save_time:>20.3f} save/s : "
        f"{load_n / load_time:>20.3f} load+sum/s : "
        f"{1 / total_time: >20.3f} total speed"
    )


def verify(df, loader, saver):
    saver(df)
    loaded = loader()
    assert np.allclose(loaded.a.sum(), df.a.sum())
    assert np.allclose(loaded.b.sum(), df.b.sum())
    assert list(loaded.columns) == list(df.columns), loaded.columns


def save_feather(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    df.to_feather("dummy.feather")


def load_feather():
    df = pd.read_feather("dummy.feather")
    df.set_index("dt", inplace=True)
    return df


def main():
    df = generate_data(5_000_000)
    benchmark(df, "dummy", lambda df: None, lambda: df)
    benchmark(df, "csv", lambda df: df.to_csv("dummy.csv"), lambda: pd.read_csv("dummy.csv", index_col="dt"))
    benchmark(df, "hdf", lambda df: df.to_hdf("dummy.h5", "dummy"), lambda: pd.read_hdf("dummy.h5", "dummy"))
    benchmark(df, "pickle", lambda df: df.to_pickle("dummy.pickle"), lambda: pd.read_pickle("dummy.pickle"))
    benchmark(df, "feather", save_feather, load_feather)
    benchmark(
        df,
        "parquet",
        lambda df: df.to_parquet("dummy.parquet", allow_truncated_timestamps=True),
        lambda: pd.read_parquet("dummy.parquet"),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

On my box (Ryzen 7 3700X, SSD disk, Windows 10, Python 3.8, newest Pandas and such) and a million-row DF (couldn't be bothered to wait for CSV results), I get

```
dummy           :         10475677.467 save/s :              186.737 load+sum/s :              186.734 total speed
csv             :                0.185 save/s :                0.970 load+sum/s :                0.156 total speed
hdf             :               18.289 save/s :               28.514 load+sum/s :               11.142 total speed
pickle          :               14.058 save/s :               31.962 load+sum/s :                9.764 total speed
feather         :               34.766 save/s :               41.436 load+sum/s :               18.904 total speed
parquet         :                7.707 save/s :               19.603 load+sum/s :                5.532 total speed
```

so HDF5 definitely isn't orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: How can you make benchmarks so quickly xD
And yeah, your results show me that feather really is the fastest with no parameters that could improve the other functions.
I'll probably stick with feather and try to accelerate it !